# Not reading CSV correctly when any date field is there

Tags: c#, csv

csv file data -

```
DB   PID  Date1       Date2
--------------------------------
DB1  561  06-04-2015  06-05-2015
DB2  538  06-04-2015  08-21-2015
DB3  722  06-04-2015  08-21-2015
```

Here date format is stated as `MM-DD-YYYY`. Problem is while reading Date2 columns date then it's reading date as `DD-MM-YYYY`. That's why in 08-21-2015 '08' becomes DD and '21' becomes month and got validation error.

Tried to solve the code :

```
Date2Val = Convert.ToDateTime(TestContext.DataRow["Date2"]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy 00:00:00.000");
```

It works for Date1 column but not for Date2.

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.ToDateTime` uses [standard date and time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of your `CurrentCulture`.

That means your `CurrentCulture` has `dd-MM-yyyy` as a standard date and time format, not `MM-dd-yyyy`.

You can *explicitly* specify your format with [custom date and time specifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ParseExact(v=vs.110).aspx) method like;

```
Date2Val = DateTime.ParseExact(TestContext.DataRow["Date2"].ToString(), 
                               "MM-dd-yyyy",
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                               .ToString("dd-MM-yyyy 00:00:00.000");
```

Comment: Error -1: The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.ParseExact(string, string, System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments. 
|Error -2: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string' Getting these error.

Comment: @RupamRouth Hmm, looks like your `TestContext.DataRow["Date2"]` returns `object`, not a `string`. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly state the format for the date value, as `DateTime.Parse` always uses the date format that's configured in your system's culture information.

The following uses the format you need:

```
Date2Val = DateTime.ParseExact(TestContext.DataRow["Date2"].ToString(), "MM-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy 00:00:00.000");
```

---

After much ado you just told us there's not only a date value in `Date2`, but also a time part. In that case you need to use this:

```
Date2Val = DateTime.ParseExact(TestContext.DataRow["Date2"].ToString(), "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy 00:00:00.000");
```

Comment: Error -1: The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.ParseExact(string, string, System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments.
Error -2: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string' 

Getting these error.

Comment: Well, what does that tell you? You need the first parameter to be a string - I'll edit my answer...

Comment: It tells this
System.FormatException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233033
  Message=String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
       at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider)

Comment: Well, what's the value in `TestContext.DataRow["Date2"]` that causes the error? Maybe the error is not as you think the fact that the month and day are mixed, but maybe there's a row that contains an empty string or any other totally invalid value?

Comment: In csv the original value is 06-05-2015.

Comment: While reading get data as {05-06-2015 00:00:00}.
But Date2Val = "" is getting.

Comment: Impossible. Above you said you get an exception. What's the exact value being passed in to `ParseExact` that throws the invalid date format exception?

Comment: Yes getting the exception. I was running code in debug tests and whatever value is getting step by step I'm stating here.

Comment: After that when I move again then getting this error -
An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: OK. Again: *what value* is in `Date2` when you get the **exception**?

Comment: {05-06-2015 00:00:00}

Comment: Well, **of course** this throws an exception. It is not the format you told us it would be. You said it would be `05-06-2015`. Instead you now say it is `05-06-2015 00:00:00`. There's a time-part you didn't talk about before. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @RupamRouth Please provide all code that reads the data from the CSV file. Thinking about it I came to the conclusion that `TestContext.DataRow["Date2"]` already contains the wrong format, and it must be filled somewhere. Please edit your question to provide that information.

Comment: Not able to paste it here as it's too long as well as I'm new in C# and also new in this site so just having 8 reputations and unable to start chat also.

Comment: Well, then unfortunately I am not able to help you any further. All I can say is that I assume the error to be in the code that fills your `TestContext` instead of the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps force the data to strings, to prevent the auto-conversion and then in the code parse it to a DateTime.
I put double qoutes around the data top force it as text. That gives back strings, without removing the quotes.

```
columnInt, columnString
1, "11.12.89"  
2, "12.12.89"
```